# Can't Sendkeys to input field in Android

Tags: c#, android, appium

I'm trying to set some  text to input for ELEMENT
But when I trying do this like ELEMENT.SendKeys() nothing happens.
I can click into the input field (It means ELEMENT with right XPath).

Xpath looks like: "//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id="amount"]"
Text value is empty
only @content-desc have a value

What should I do for simulating set text to the field ELEMENT?

Comment: are there any errors? logs?

Comment: Please provide a complete code example illustrating what you are doing.

Comment: There is no errors. Sendkeys method doesn't work. That's all.  Element with right xpath (I can click on it). I tried send request with command prompt like "adb shell input text some_text" after clicking on field. And with command prompt I can set text into field. But from the autotests I can't do this with Sendkeys("some_text").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you are using `Xpath` you need to put **full resourceId value** (with package name)
Assuming you are using instance of `AndroidDriver` as `driver` you can do this in Java:

```
AndroidElement editElement = driver.findElement(By.id("amount"));
editElement.setValue(value);
```

Comment: Yeah! It's helps! But I trying editElement.SetImmediateValue(); Thank you so much!